# strtol gives segfault when strtok returns NULL

Tags: c, csv, file-handling, strtok, strtol

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* getfield(char* line, int num) {
        const char* tok;
        for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
                tok && *tok;
                tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
        {
            if (!--num)
                return tok;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE* stream = fopen("b.csv", "r");
        char line[1024];
        char *pstr;int num;
         const char* value;

        while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
        {
            char* tmp = strdup(line);
        //printf("Field 3 would be %s\n", getfield(tmp, 3));    
        value=getfield(tmp, 3);
        num =strtol(value,&pstr,10);
        printf("Field 3 would be %d\n", num);
        // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
```

/* b.csv

```
301,36,15
302,88,75
```

/ / my output

```
Field 3 would be 15
Field 3 would be 75
```

*/

issue is : /* b.csv

```
301,36,15
 302,88,
 ,,,34
```

if the the table is broken as above "strtok" returns NULL ,and so "strtol" gives "segfault"..how to resolve it ?

Here the main issue is if  2nd is not present, it treats 3rd as a second and gives segfault !!  for example in a 3rd row of b.csv ",,,34" is there means  3rd value is present, but It behaves like "34" is a 1st value and 2nd and third are respectively NULL !!

Comment: So, you are calling `strtol` on a `NULL` pointer? That will never work. Check for `NULL` _before_ calling anything using that pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just check the `value` that you get from `getfield(tmp, 3);` for `NULL` and not call `strtol` if `NULL` is returned? Another way  to get around is make a `static char* not_found = "";` in `getfield` and return address to it instead of `NULL`, then `strtol` will not segfault.

**UPDATE**

Since i found that `strtok` really is helpless in this situation i tried to write code that does the same with `strchr`:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    char* getfield(char* line, int num) {
        char* tok = line;
        char* result;
        if (line)
        {
            do
            {
                if (!--num)
                {
                    tok = strchr(line, ',');
                    if (tok == NULL)
                    {
                        tok = &line[strlen(line)];
                    }
                    size_t fieldlen = tok - line;
                    if (fieldlen)
                    {
                        result = (char*)malloc(fieldlen+1);
                        result[fieldlen] = '\0';
                        strncpy(result, line, fieldlen);
                        return result;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                tok = strchr(line, ',');
                line = tok + 1;
            } while (tok);
        }
        result = (char*)malloc(2);
        strcpy(result, "0");
        return result;
    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE* stream = fopen("b.csv", "r");
        char line[1024];
        char *pstr;int num;
        char* value;

        while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
        {
            char* tmp = strdup(line);
            //printf("Field 3 would be %s\n", getfield(tmp, 3));    
            value=getfield(tmp, 3);
            num =strtol(value,&pstr,10);
            free(value);
            printf("Field 3 would be %d\n", num);
            // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
```

This worked on input file:

```
    10,,30
    10,
```

The code returns `0` if nothing is found, you can change that, and the result is dynamically allocated. I hope this helps, the lesson for me is - avoid C when parsing strings :D

Comment: see, if any value is missing I suppose to assign it Value "0" so it would not take 3rd as a second, if second is missing... so I thought to assign it from the calling function,but can't add properly... do you have any idea how to resolve it ?

Comment: according to POSIX specification, `strtok` treats two consecutive delimiters as one, so, it's a bit tricky to solve: uyou can use `strchr` on the line to actually find and extract the stuff between `,`, either use the regex  features in C++, use c++ strings , ...

Comment: Thats why I was asking that Is is possible that I can assign value "0" (as a string) from "getfield" itself.. so It can return it and the issue of  two consecutive delimiters can be solved. And I can not use C++ as I suppose to do in C only.

Comment: Updated the answer with solution that uses `strchr` and hopefully works.

Comment: value=getfield(tmp, 1); value2=getfield(tmp, 2);value3=getfield(tmp, 3);  it means there are  I was suggesting you compare the current
   3 x getfield()   (involving malloc + assorted strchr, etc)
   3 x strtol()
   3 x free()     with the large amount of data It is very time consuming !!! when I want to assign it somewhere else on every "reload" It gives me errors....can you help to improve performance of this code ??

Comment: Well, pass in the memory buffer for the result as a parameter to `getfield()` that is a stack variable in `main()`, that way you can avoid `malloc()` and `free()`.

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
num =strtol(value,&pstr,10);
printf("Field 3 would be %d\n", num);
```

use this:

```
if (value!=NULL) {         
    num =strtol(value,&pstr,10);
    printf("Field 3 would be %d\n", num);
}
else {
    printf("Field 3 does not exist\n");
}
```

you have to check if `value!= NULL` before calling `strtol()` function

**Edit** to fix the return of `getfield()` function

In the for loop try to change: (I did not test it but it could solve your problem)

```
 tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n")
```

by

```
 tok = strtok(tok+strlen(tok)+1, ",\n")
```

Comment: with this method the second issue can not be solved... eg. value in file is "10,,30" here It treats 30 as a second value and NULL as a 3rd value... so no segfault here but the value is ultimately wrong

Comment: in this case you have to update the getfield() to return the right value